# position in jQuery on hover()

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to jQuery solution and I know that a lot of you are using this so maybe someone will be able to help me on this.

I am trying to change to position of a div on the hover of another element.

Here's the code I have tried:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".NEWS_menu").hover(function(){$("#dropdown_NEWS").position({
my: "bottom",
at: "top",
of: ".NEWS_menu"
})});

</script>

<ul class="lithos gradient" id="menu">
    <li><a class="NEWS_menu" href="/news/index.php"><span class="BIGLETTER">N</span>ouvelles</a>
        <div id="dropdown_NEWS">
            <a class="ARTICLES_link" href="#"><span class="BIGLETTER">A</span>rticles</a>
        </div>
    </li>
[...]
```

[academiemarisa.com](http://academiemarisa.com) if you want to see what it is suposed to give me.

The code is not uploaded yet. I am trying to get it to work with jquery first.

Right now, it is working with CSS :hover very well but for compatibilty reason, I need jQuery for that.

If someone could help me on the positioning of jQuery.

Thanks

Comment: you cannot use `.position()` to change the position of an object, it only returns the current position. You want to move the image of the menu depending of the menu position?

Comment: the example you gave us above doesn't use the regular jQuery position() method but jQueryUI's position method. jQueryUI is jQuery's UserInterface library, see here http://api.jqueryui.com/position .
in order to use this snipper above you have to include jqueryUI as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that #dropdown_NEWS is absolutely positioned, you can use jQuery css method to position it under the menu which was hovered. Maybe something like this:

```
$(".NEWS_menu").hover(function(){$("#dropdown_NEWS").css({ "left": "value", "top": "value", })});
```